# Browsers and Postman doesn't decode UTF-8 filename in Content-Disposition header

Tags: java, http, utf-8, filenames, content-disposition

so I have the situation when I need to return CSV/excel file on a POST request. The problem is to return the filename in different languages, such as Chinese, German, etc.  As far as I know, there're 2  ways to do that:

1. to return `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="привет.txt"`
2. to return `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''%some%encoded%name.txt"`.

Both of them do not work with Postman/Browser, but the second one works fine with Swagger. The first way returns something like this `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="???.txt"`. The second one returns absolutely the same text of filename quotes (encoded UTF-8, for instance: `UTF-8''%some%encoded%name.txt`.  I'm using Java Spring stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was to process that Content-Disposition header on the UI part by encoding it after UTF-8'' symbols.